# Can you retrieve a list of updated rows when running an UPDATE query using the Go sqlx package with Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, sqlx

I have a query I'm running using Go's sqlx package (an extension to the standard database/sql package) with a Postgres database. It looks something like this:

```
result, err := s.getDB(tx).Exec(`
    UPDATE table_name
    SET var_name = 0
    WHERE var_name = 1;`)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Without using a managed transaction, how can I retrieve the list of updated rows? Or at least a list of primary keys for the updated rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PostgreSQL's `RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) and `db.Query/db.Select` variants instead of `Exec`, e.g.

```
//get the primary key of updated rows
db := s.getDB(tx)

results := []int{}
err = db.Select(&results, "UPDATE mytable SET var_name = 0 WHERE var_name = 1 RETURNING id")
```

To retrieve more than one columns, just list the column names after `RETURNING`, e.g.

```
rows, err := db.Queryx("UPDATE mytable SET var_name = 0 WHERE var_name = 1 RETURNING id,var_name,other_columns")
for rows.Next() {
    //do something with the result
}
```